# Html5 Cross-platform Desktop application

Tags: html, desktop-application

I have developed an POS system for a Restaurant in HTML running in Firefox. This is working well, and with some fixes in the about:config file of Firefox I can get it to run relatively smooth (e.g. suppress the print dialogue). However Html does not have full access to printers and scanners the way a native desktop application has.

I'm now looking for a solution that I can develop a native desktop application for Mac and PC but keep what I have, by showing it a sort of "Web View" ( I know this from Objective-C/Xcode programming). The idea is to have the software watch out for links in the HTML code, e.g.

Print Kitchen Recipe

Can anyone give me a hint which language and  software development environment I should work with, my current skills are:

Html, PHP, Mysql - Excellent
Objective-C / Xcode - Medium
Javascript - Medium

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0):

Checkout node.js and its WebKit module. It can run natively packed JavaScript and you can easily write c style extensions to do anything else you need.